# Google / Firebase Analytics getting application usage peak times

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am currently trying to get the peak times users access my application. It seems Firebase and Google do not provide this information anymore. Is this correct or is there a way to get this information? Thank you in advance!